# Buildfire - How to get context for how a user arrives to your plugin for navigation purposes?

Tags: buildfire

I recently developed a plugin that acts as a gateway to other plugins.  Users get linked to other plugins and will be redirected if they are authenticated.  There is an issue that occurs after this redirection however.  When a user tries to use the built in navigation to move back to the previous plugin, they are essentially stuck.  This is because they move backwards in the history to the gateway plugin, which then just redirects back to the linked plugin again.

I would like to be able to prevent this and have the user travel back to the plugin before the gateway plugin to prevent this redirect loop.  I have found that the method buildfire.navigation.goBack() will potentially work.  The only problem that exists now though is that I do not know how to tell the context for how I arrived at gateway plugin.

Is there as way to tell if I arrive at the plugin through the click of the back button versus if I was deep linked to the plugin directly from a different place in the app?

Comment: Is there anything in the documentation about this?  I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

If these are your plugins, you can take advantage of BuildFire localStorage. You can write the value of the current plugin like so:

```
buildfire.localStorage.setItem("currentPlugin","myPlugin");
```

and then in your gateway plugin:

```
buildfire.localStorage.getItem("currentPlugin", function(error, value){
 //Check "value" to see how to handle redirect
```

});

https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/LocalStorage

This of course would only work for plugins that you developed.

Comment: That is the main problem I am having at the moment.  I need a solution that works for any plugin, not just ones that I develop.  If my plugin redirects someone to a plugin that I have not created, which is more than likely, then I have no way to save that context.  When I return back to my gateway plugin I will still have no idea whether I arrived after going backward or forward.  Is there no context clue that BuildFire exposes?  Even the history array itself doesn't help as it only shows the history up until the gateway plugin since the plugin it came from gets popped off.